# Is it natural and correct to say "rig one's data expenditure" meaning to make it look like someone spends more than they really do?

Tags: phrases, collocations

Could you tell me if it is natural and correct to say *rig one's data expenditure* meaning to make it look like someone spends more than they really do? For example:

> The customer accuses the service provider of **rigging his data expenditure**. He says he spent 20GB of data last month and an app on his phone backs it up, but the carrier says he spent 30GB.

If it sounds off, would you tell me how you would say it?

Comment: Is the customer accusing the service provider of making a mistake with the data usage figure, or of deliberately falsifying it?

Comment: Deliberately falsifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rig something, in this context, means "*to manipulate or control usually by deceptive or dishonest means*" [Merriam-Webster, verb(2) def #1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rig). They key in your example is what the direct object of "rig" is.

If the ISP (Internet Service Provider) rigged "his data expenditure", it would mean they were manipulating how much data he actually used, as in, causing him to use more data than he ordinarily would have, perhaps by purposefully transmitting 10 GB of garbage data to his phone.

However, if the intent is they're just faking the numbers, then you'd need something like "*rigging his data expenditure **figures/measurement/etc.***".

Also, unless the ISP uses the words "expenditure" and "spend", I would use the words "usage" and "use".